# how to pass state using navigator in react native navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to pass a state using react navigator. I want to pass showing: false, so my progress bar component will disappear.Can someone please explain how I can do this. Thanks so much.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import ContinueButton from "./ContinueButton";
import { CreateAboutMe } from "./StyleSheet/AboutMeStyle";
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";

export class AboutUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigatToInterests = this.navigatToInterests.bind(this);
    this.checkEntry = this.checkEntry.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      showing: true,
    };
  }

  navigatToInterests = ({ navigation }) => {
    let checkDescription = this.state.value;
    if (checkDescription === "") {
      alert("Please tell people about yourself");
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Interests");
    }
  };

  checkEntry = (Description, value) => {
    this.setState({ value: value });
    console.log(this.state.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={CreateAboutMe.overAllContainer}>
        {this.state.showing && (
          <Progress.Bar
            progress={0.7667}
            width={300}
            color={"red"}
            style={CreateAboutMe.progressbar}
            showing={this.state.showing}
          />
        )}
```

Comment: you want to pass props in the "Interests" component while navigation using this.props.navigation ?

Comment: if this.state.showing is false then your Progress.Bar component is never going to render because you added a conditional rendering. so, If you maintain a boolean in the Progress.Bar then there is no need for this check "this.state.showing &&"

Answer (score 1):

Which version of React Navigation are you using?

In version 4, you can send some data using the second argument of the navigate function like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Interests",{"someKey":"someValue", ...});
```

Then you can grab the data in the next page through the props:

```
let someValue = this.props.navigation.getParam('someKey');
```